# Academic Papers about UI

Tags: research

Are there any academic papers (thesis, dissertations, etc.) that discusses topics about User Interfaces? Best if you post links.

I am just curious if such topics are accepted for research...

Comment: I am overwhelmed with your answers, thanks guys! =)

Comment: Come and tell us when you have read all of that, and will find some more. And yes, I am researching in HCI at the moment.

Comment: anything from sigchi and cscw (acm special interest groups should have some good results)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Indeed, *lots* of research has been done on User Interfaces. Try and search the [ACM Digital Library](http://portal.acm.org/) for terms like "GOMS", "Heuristics", "Fitts's Law", "Cognitive Walkthrough", "Consistency", "HCI", "modes", "prototypes" ... and "User Interface".

The research discipline is so extensive that I think you need to specify your question in order to get relevant links.

(And then there's the entire User Experience discipline with terms like "desirability", "emotions" etc.)

Answer (score 4):

At the BCS HCI / Interaction Specialist group, you can look at the past 13years of quarterlys for free http://www.bcs.org/content/conWebDoc/36812

The HCI Bibliography http://www.hcibib.org/

Answer (score 3):

There also many gems in Nielsen's Alertbox:

http://www.useit.com/alertbox/

Answer (score 2):

Look at the CHI conference proceedings over the last 30 odd years (:

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find all usability guidelines: (reliable resource, but not the freshest studies)
http://www.usability.gov/guidelines/

Answer (score 1):

You can also checkout individual academic professor's websites, such as B.J. Fogg, who is a professor of persuasive design at Stanford University. http://www.bjfogg.com/

Answer (score 1):

Usability Professionals' Association publications: http://www.upassoc.org/upa_publications/index.html

Comment: Ugh why is their site so ugly though?

Comment: Yeah, it looks rather dated and doesn't communicate ease of use... And why is http://www.uxmatters.com/ so purple??? :)