# How can I convey the results of UX research to stakeholders?

Tags: interaction-design, usability, research, usability-study

How can I go about getting stakeholders to understand and "buy into" the results derived from UX research? For example, I ran across this great [UX research plan](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/01/26/ux-research-plan-stakeholders-love/) by a Google UX researcher today.

Comment: Adam, unfortunately, UX.SE is for "solvable" questions only [per our FAQ](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq). If you wish to solicit examples, please post this question on Quora or another discussion board.

Comment: Really confused on this one.  What makes this question unsolvable?  If someone were to post a couple plans they have found that help them get stakeholder buy-in, I'd consider it solved.  There are many similar questions.  For example, here's one that asks for examples of UI research, which is much less specific than this question. http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3080/academic-papers-about-ui

Comment: The question you showed as an example is dated a year ago when this section was barely 6 months old. Enforcement of question guidelines has increased since then (and especially in the last month since we have come out of beta).

Comment: I have edited the question to fit better on the site to the best of my interpretation of what @Adam is looking for.

Comment: @dnbrv Okay.  The other question didn't meet guidelines either.  Cool.  Can you help me understand what aspect of the question you saw as unsolvable so I can understand what part of it conflicted with the guidelines?

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I like your rewording in the body.  To paraphrase it, "How to get stakeholder buy-in for proposed UX research initiatives?".  I thought it might be appropriate to remove the "best" qualifier from the question too, in line with  http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/665/why-do-people-ask-for-the-best-how-can-we-discourage-it.  Would my paraphrased version meet the criteria for a good question in your view?

Comment: Is this title/body edit more appropriate? I feel more detail as to why you feel the need to ask (have stakeholders not been responsive in the past?) would help but I can't provide that.

Comment: Ben, Matt edited the question to ask for a solution to a problem I don't have. I didn't want to edit over his edits without asking, so I paraphrased it and asked for feedback on my revision first.  After not getting a response, I posted my revision as a separate question at: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16884/how-to-get-stakeholder-buy-in-for-proposed-ux-research-initiatives.

Comment: That said, I think this is still a good question, especially with your re-write.  I actually have an answer for this, though I won't have time to write it for a few days.  This may make a good meta topic on editing protocols.  Asking before editing would help the asker learn from the question, before it suddenly becomes a different question with the original deleted.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to get very practical and base this solely on my own war stories:

1. Part of the trick is speaking the stakeholder's language - actually incorporating some of their vernacular and giving credit even where credit is "don't" ;)
2. Use mechanisms they feel comfortable with, as in: the mighty Power Point. Even if it's one slide. And the whole thing is a video.
3. You really need to ease them into your findings. I get so excited sometimes and end up "flooding the engine" by trying to get to the meat of it. Find that balance between "too much fluff" and "straight to the point". Play it by ear. This is art.
4. Don't get discouraged by lack of immediate buy-in or even opposition. Executives believe they know their customers, they need time to think, or pretend like they are thinking - all to create an appearance that they know a few things too. They come around eventually, unless your work is worthless.

Comment: To #1 I'd add: Use examples/comparisons from competitors in with the stakeholder's language.  that gets their attention.